# Disable backwards animation in unslider slideshow

Tags: jquery, css

I have a banner slideshow set up using unslider (unslider.com) that is technically behaving correctly. However, I do not want it to do the backwards animation back to first slide when last slide is over. I want it to just go to first slide in same manner that all the other slide transitions behave. I cannot figure this out.

Code below and working demo here:

http://codepen.io/trevoray/pen/GgPGaB

---

```
  <div id="hp-banner">
   <div id="hp-banner-left" class=banner>
      <ul>
         <li id="image1">
            <a href="/test.php" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 0; position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 100px;"></a>
            <a href="/test.php" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 0; position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 400px;"></a>
         </li>
         <li id="image2"></li>
         <li id="image3"></li>
         <li id="image4"></li>
         <li id="image5"></li>
      </ul>
   </div>

   <div id="hp-banner-right">
      <ul>
         <li><a href="">banner 1</a></li>
         <li><a href="">banner 2</a></li>
         <li><a href="">banner 3</a></li>
         <li><a href="">banner 4</a></li>
         <li><a href="">banner 5</a></li>
      </ul>


   </div>

   <!-- hp banner end -->
</div>
```

---

```
 <style>
   #hp-banner {
      width: 1024px;
   }
   #hp-banner-left {
      float: left;
      width: 680px;
      height: 200px;
   }
   #hp-banner-right ul {
      width: 324px;
      float: left;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
   }
   #hp-banner-right ul li {
      list-style: none;
      line-height: 38px;
      height: 38px;
      background: #f9fafb;
      position: relative;
      color: #8d8d69;
      text-align: center;
      border: solid thin #cbcccc;
   }
   #hp-banner-right ul li:hover,
   #hp-banner-right ul li.active {
      color: white;
      background: #4882c3;
   }
   #hp-banner-right ul li:hover:before,
   #hp-banner-right ul li.active:before {
      content: '';
      border-top: 19px solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 19px solid transparent;
      border-right: 38px solid #4882c3;
      position: absolute;
      right: 100%;
      top: 0;
   }
   .banner {
      position: relative;
      overflow: auto;
      width: 680px;
   }
   .banner ul {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
   }
   .banner li {
      list-style: none;
   }
   .banner ul li {
      float: left;
      display: block;
      max-width: 100%;
      height: 200px;
      /*        -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;*/

      -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
      -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
      -ms-background-size: 100% 100%;
      /*        background-size: 100% 100%;*/
   }
   #image1 {
      background-image: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/189477/image1.jpg");
   }
   #image2 {
      background-image: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/189477/image2.jpg");
   }
   #image3 {
      background-image: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/189477/image3.jpg");
   }
   #image4 {
      background-image: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/189477/image4.jpg");
   }
   #image5 {
      background-image: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/189477/image5.jpg");
   }
</style>
```

---

```
 <script>
   $(function() {
      $('.banner').unslider({
         speed: 500, //  The speed to animate each slide (in milliseconds)
         delay: 2000,
         dots: true,
         complete: function() {
            var index = $('#hp-banner .dot.active').index();
            $('#hp-banner-right li').removeClass('active').eq(index).addClass('active');
         }
      });
   });


   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#hp-banner-right li').first().addClass('active');
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would probably be best to switch to another slideshow plugin [like FlexSlider 2](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/), but if you're committed to using Unslider there's a hacky way you can accomplish what you want to.

Add a duplicate of your first image to the end of the list

```
<ul>
    <li class="image1"></li>
    <li class="image2"></li>
    <li class="image3"></li>
    <li class="image4"></li>
    <li class="image5"></li>
    <li class="image1"></li> <!-- Repeat first list item -->
</ul>
```

Then when unslider reaches the last slide (the duplicate), the following code should run in the complete callback.

```
if (index == $("#hp-banner-right li").length)
{
  var data = slidey.data('unslider');
  data.speed = 0;
  data.move(0, function () {})
  data.speed = 500;
  $('#hp-banner-right li').removeClass ('active').eq (0).addClass ('active');
}
```

Which will set the speed of the transition to 0 temporarily so the slider seamlessly switches to the actual first list item.

[You can see all of this together in my CodePen.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqNEoE)

Comment: Thanks so much! Exactly what I needed. I'll keep FlexSlider in mind for future projects.

Comment: Sorry for delay in bounty. It wouldn't let me do it when I accepted answer and then I just forgot about it.

Answer (score 0):

When i was trying to apply the hack from 'Harangue' i figured out the code and i found that you can just use the option: `infinite: true` to achieve this. So, no hacking needed! It's just not documented that well.

source:

```
- unslider.js v2.0 on line 465 contains the following code:

if(self.options.infinite) {
    //  So then we need to hide the first slide
    self.$container.css('margin-' + prop, '-100%');
}
```